# Adding columns to a pivot table in excel

Tags: excel

I apologize if my question is vague or was asked before. I have the below table in a spreadsheet

```
Region    Next Service Date   Duration Type   Duration Frequency
New York  12/4/2013           Year            1
```

The spreadsheet has 4 columns and what I would like to do is to create a pivot table and somehow project the next 24 months service duration on the pivot table so the output would look like the below

> Count of Unit Serial Number   Column Labels   Continue for 
>       Mar-13  24 Months…
>   Region
>   New York    Count of Services

Basically, I need to show the count of services for the next 24 months without editing the datasource tab of the pivot table.

As far as I know, you can't add columns to a pivot table.

If someone gives me an idea of how to add columns based on the duration and duration frequency to a pivot table, that would be a great start point.

Thank you all for your feedback and sorry for the misformatted tables

Comment: Might not be the best solution but when I want to do math on pivot table results, I copy and paste the table as values to a new tab then play with it.

Comment: Can someone please tell me how to insert a excel table into a question? I have done it once, I can't do it now. Thank you

Comment: You could take a screenshot and insert that.

Comment: Either use a screenshot as Doug suggested (if you don't have enough rep, just post a link in a comment) - or use http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html to get well formatted text from a table.

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula

In cell A1 of Sheet2

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

Copy and paste as needed, you now have a duplicate of the data sheet, "without editing the datasource".

Create your formulas for projection info on Sheet2, and use Sheet2 as the source for the Pivot Table.

Be aware lots of formulas can bog down Excel, so if at all possible I would put your formulas for projection info on the datsource tab (Sheet1) and hide them.  You will still be able to use them in the Pivot table when hidden.